# What does passing a parameter mean? in C#

Tags: c#, parameters

Im fairly new to c# programming. What does passing a parameter mean? and can someone give me an example please?

Thank you.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really a good site to learn a language from scratch. I suggest you get a good introductory book, which should cover this along with everything else. I *do* have an [article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) but if you don't know anything about parameters to start with, it's unlikely to be terribly helpful.

Comment: [Passing Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx)

Comment: Your question doesn't directly relate to C#. You must first learn **thinking in a computer program** and then **programming**

Comment: [It's not a C# concept.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)) Also, the Stack Overflow community doesn't like questions which can be answered by a simple [google search (about 26,600,000 results)](https://www.google.com/search?q=passing+a+parameter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in languages such as C# (and many, many, others) can take "parameters".  These are things you pass in to let the function do whatever it was designed to do.  Consider:

```
public int Add(int x, int y)
{
   return x + y;
}

int a = 5;
int b = 5;

int sum = Add(a, b);
```

In the above example, we are passing the variables `a` and `b` to the function `Add`.  The function takes two parameters, `x` and `y`, and adds them together returning the result.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I understand parameters a lot better now.

Answer (score 0):

In simple sense,passing a parameter means to give an input to the function. let me give you an example

below is the algorithm for adding two numbers and printing the result

```
void add(int a,int b)
{
    int sum
    sum=a+b
    print sum 
}
```

So we have defined a function. The function add contains two arguments. An argument is a 'holder' for the values ie a variable.Now it expects two parameters( input) a and b.

Hence to use this function we must call it like this

```
add(1,2)
```

the numbers inside the paranthesis are called parameters. they are input for your function

Comment: Yes :) I don't know c#. so I used a psuedocode to clarify it. Thankx for the notice and edit :)

Comment: Your "pseudocode" function nevertheless seems like it could use a return statement.

Comment: Edited. Sorry but I am still newbie in programming