# Is there any difference between the terms "arguments" and "parameters" in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know the difference between arguments and parameters, but I'am a bit confused about how jQuery uses these terms.

For instance, jQuery defines as "parameters" the options passed to the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method. These shouldn't be declared as arguments because you pass your own values?

Then, on [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function you can find many times the terms "parameters" and "arguments". For example, if you search for the `beforeSend` property, you'll see:

> The jqXHR and settings objects are passed as arguments.

But, in another section you'll also see:

> The callback hooks provided by $.ajax() are as follows:
>
> beforeSend callback option is invoked; it receives the jqXHR object
>   and the settings object as parameters.

Does it mean that jQuery uses equally the terms "parameters" and "arguments"?

Comment: Why are we answering a question that has been asked and answered before on StackOverflow AND is a simple Google search?

Comment: Of course, I have seen all the answers but why jQuery uses both terms for the `beforeSend` callback. See my example. These should be arguments, right?

Comment: The first case says that the jQuery code that internally invokes `beforeSend` passes in those arguments. The second case says that the `beforeSend` function should *be parameterized* (i.e., have parameters) to receive the jqXHR object and settings object. The difference may seem very small, but that's because the difference between arguments and parameters is quite small. I admit it's possible that the human who wrote this particular piece of jQuery documentation could have been slightly clearer about the minutia of arguments vs. parameters, for whatever benefit that would bring.

Comment: @apsillers Thanks for taking the time to explain it!

Answer (score 1):

"A parameter is a variable in a method definition. When a method is called, the arguments are the data you pass into the method's parameters."

[What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156767/whats-the-difference-between-an-argument-and-a-parameter)

Answer (score -1):

"parameters" are passed , "arguments" are received

---

See

[What does passing a parameter mean? in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781434/what-does-passing-a-parameter-mean-in-c-sharp)

[Parameters and arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming)#Parameters_and_arguments)

[What is an 'Argument' in Programming means?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-Argument-in-Programming-means)

Comment: Even though it's semantics, I think this is technically incorrect.  Although, I can't imagine a situation in which someone would be confused by using them interchangeably.